# Failed to use wasm function on vue

Tags: typescript, vue.js, go, webassembly

When I want to use wasm in vue, the first thing is that I have an unsolvable problem, the startQuorum function in my wasm file can't be found.

```js
import { Go } from './wasm_exec'
import quorumWasmUrl from './lib.wasm'

export const startQuorum = async (bootstraps: Array<string>) => {
  const go = new Go()
  WebAssembly.instantiateStreaming(fetch(quorumWasmUrl), go.importObject).then(
    async (result) => {
      go.run(result.instance)
      const StartQuorum = result.instance.exports.StartQuorum as CallableFunction
      // StartQuorum is a function. but ts can not find it.
      await StartQuorum('password', bootstraps.join(','))
    }
  )
  console.log('startQuorum over')
}
```

And the wasm files written in Go.The original function is like this

```golang
js.Global().Set("StartQuorum", js.FuncOf(func(this js.Value, args []js.Value) interface{} {
        if qChan == nil {
            qChan = make(chan struct{}, 0)
        }
        if len(args) < 2 {
            return nil
        }
        password := args[0].String()
        bootAddrsStr := args[1].String()
        bootAddrs := strings.Split(bootAddrsStr, ",")

        handler := func() (map[string]interface{}, error) {
            ret := make(map[string]interface{})
            ok, err := StartQuorum(qChan, password, bootAddrs)
            ret["ok"] = ok
            if err != nil {
                return ret, err
            }
            return ret, nil
        }
        return Promisefy(handler)
    }))
```

That means the StartQuorum function in wasm is existed, but typescript can't find it, browser return this.

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: StartQuorum is not a function
at eval (load-quorum.ts?b7b7:139:1)
```

The wasm file is loaded well, my initial diagnosis is that ts does not recognize the functions in wasm.

How can I solve it?

Comment: "That means the StartQuorum function in wasm is existed, but typescript can't find it" - it doesn't mean that. TS errors occur at compilation time, while you have an error at runtime. The error means that StartQuorum is really not a function, and it would be the same with JS. Apart from wasm subject, you can debug what StartQuorum value is and proceed from that

Comment: Emmm... I ignored the error and ran the program directly, and it ran successfully....but typescript still warns about function not found. hhhhhh

Answer (score 1):

That happens because it's not an exported function. Currently, Golang Compiler doesn't support export function (only importing, by magic `CALLIMPORT` assembly instruction). *I'm saying "Golang Compiler" because that is not true if you are using TinyGo or other compiler*.

---

Anyway, using `js.Global().Set` will set the function into the `js.Global()`, which is `window`/`globalThis` or equivalent:

```
js.Global().Set("StartQuorum", ....)
```

That is creating the `StartQuorum` function at the `window`/`globalThis` level. So, the function must be called using: `window.StartQuorum()`.

---

So, this line:

```
const StartQuorum = result.instance.exports.StartQuorum as CallableFunction
// StartQuorum is a function. but ts can not find it.

await StartQuorum('password', bootstraps.join(','))
```

Doesn't seems to make sense, since `result.instance.exports.StartQuorum` is always null. Your function lives on `window.StartQuorum` or `globalThis.StartQuorum` (...).

*That is not one exported function from WebAssembly (which will live at `result.instance.exports`.*